# Panning in three js

Tags: three.js

I have attached OrbitControls to one of my 3D object (.obj) and not to the camera. It works fine while rotating and zooming but 'Pan' doesnt work. It throws a warning "WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - pan disabled.".

Is there any way I can PAN my 3d object? My final aim is to pan it through keys which will happen if the panning works.